# How to save to disk HttpPostedFileBase object as a file?

Tags: c#, file-upload

How to save to disk HttpPostedFileBase object as a file? The name of the file should be the id of the alert sent to the group

```
private static string SaveSharedFile(int userAlertId, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string fileName = null;
        fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        if (fileName != "")
        { 
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
            byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
            br.Close();

            //Save HttpPostedFileBase object as file at c://Path/Folder should have userAlertId name
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Try System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename,buffer);

Answer (score 6):

if large uploads are a possibility, I would recommend not using HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream or File.WriteAllBytes. Both of these methods load the entire upload into memory on the server before handing it off to your code.

A more efficient way would be to read the file into a stream using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream() and writing the buffer based on a buffersize that you specify. This also gives you the option to write the file directly to disk *as you read it* using a second stream, minimizing memory usage and time.

Here's an example:

```
private static string SaveSharedFile(int userAlertId, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string fileName = null;
        fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        if (fileName != "")
        { 
            const int BufferSize = 65536; // 65536 = 64 Kilobytes
            string Filepath = userAlertId.ToString();  
            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(Filepath))
            {
                using (Stream reader = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
                    int read = -1, pos = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        int len = (file.ContentLength < pos + BufferSize ?
                            file.ContentLength - pos :
                            BufferSize);
                        read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, len);
                        fs.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                        pos += read;
                    } while (read > 0);
                }
            }
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

**EDIT:** The "file" variable is still used to read things like file.ContentLength but, in my example, GetBufferlessInputStream() is just an alternate place to read the post from (assuming the post is just the file, with file headers that can potentially hold form values) that allows you to choose how much to buffer at a time.

If the file is being posted with a form, together, you may just have to replace "...GetBufferlessInputStream()" with "file.InputStream()" again. But if you're still writing the buffer as you read it rather than buffering the buffer (as in your original question) it may still be efficient enough for your needs.

Comment: @usr, I like that. to integrate your suggestion into my code, I would probably use CopyTo(Stream, Int32) to keep control over the BufferSize.

Comment: @chris.nesbit1. I really appreciate your answer. However, is there any way you can use HttpPostedFileBase because, I didn't right the application, I'm just trying to use add functionality to the class. SaveSharedFile is not in the controller but inside an helper method. And this method is being called by another method that expect HttpPostedFileBase. Please, don't erase the first solution. Just add another using HttpPostedFileBase. Thanks